# Butterknife vs AndroidAnnotations

Tags: android, view, code-injection

I'm thinking about using [Dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/) in my Application. I also want to use a view injection library which gives me a lot of functionality to save time writing code, but on the other hand it shouldn't be to heavy in size and expensive when it comes to performance.

Are there any major differences between [AndroidAnnotations](http://androidannotations.org/) and [Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)?

Comment: posted the links to make it clear

Comment: Why on earth was this closed as "opinion based". All technical answers have a modicum of opinion. Guidelines to help someone pick a framework is surely not off topic for Stack Overflow? Sheesh.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you just want to reduce boilerplate code in your application by inject views (or setting click listeners), you can start with `Butterknife`. It's fast, small in size and straightforward in use. It's intended to inject views, listeners and other UI related objects.

If you want to inject more stuff like system services, or force methods to run in background or UI thread, or inject resources like animations etc. you should go after `AndroidAnnotations`.   Small disadvantage you will face is that for each class you want to enhance a new class will be generated with the same name plus "_" at the end. Thus you will have to get used to use such names when calling activities or creating fragments. If this is not an issue for you, just use it. Both libraries generate code, so you should not have any performance penalties at runtime.

`Dagger` is not intended for views injection. `Dagger` allows you to better structure your code and define injectable dependencies between different components. It's very powerful if you master it, but it does not replace `Butterknife`.

Comment: I just mentioned Daggger, because i wasn't sure about the compabilty. 
Before i used Roboguice and now i need to switch because it's not compadible with android annotations.